# Update email with Google Admin SDK

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to update my Google's organization email signatures using Ruby, in Python I had this code.

```
# client.UpdateSignature(username=gmail_user, signature=html)
```

Now I need to use Ruby but I can't access to this function, I have this code but I don't know witch & how use this API.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: "xxxxxx", application_version: "0.1")
groups = client.discovered_api('admin', 'directory_v1')
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('config/xxx69.p12', 'notasecret')
service = client.discovered_api('admin', 'directory_v1')
```

Or how to send a direct update to:

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/mydomain.com/#{user}/signature
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that simply doing a mass update of every email signature in your domain would be easier done in the GUI Google Admin panel, but I might also suggest that you look into GAM, as well: https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM. It makes many of the Google APIs much easier to deal with/ build off of.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it.